# Adding a Z prior to my query set

Tags: django

I have a few if statements, which identify a datareducecode.  Everything is working correctly except for the last one, which is number 7 in the view below:

```
if request.method == 'POST' and selectedaccesslevel == '3':
    datareducecode = OrgLevel.objects.filter(coid__exact = owner.coid.coid).values_list('slevel', flat = True)
    print (datareducecode)
if request.method == 'POST' and selectedaccesslevel == '4':
    datareducecode = OrgLevel.objects.filter(coid__exact = owner.coid.coid).values_list('blevel', flat = True)
    print (datareducecode)
if request.method == 'POST' and selectedaccesslevel == '5':
    datareducecode = OrgLevel.objects.filter(coid__exact = owner.coid.coid).values_list('rlevel', flat = True)
    print (datareducecode)
if request.method == 'POST' and selectedaccesslevel == '6':
    datareducecode = OrgLevel.objects.filter(coid__exact = owner.coid.coid).values_list('dlevel', flat = True)
    print (datareducecode)
if request.method == 'POST' and selectedaccesslevel == '7':
    datareducecode = OrgLevel.objects.filter(coid__exact = owner.coid.coid).values_list('f"Z{coid}"', flat = True)
    print (datareducecode)
```

I know it's because the values_list where I have 'f"Z{coid}"' to place a Z prior to the coid.  I get the following error message:

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'f"Z{coid}"' into field. Choices are: blevel, coid, dlevel, facilitydimension, rlevel, slevel, user
```

My question is how do I get a Z prior to the results of datareducecode for selectedaccess == 7?

datareducecode eventually get's saved to the database as `datareducecode = list(datareducecode)[0]`

Comment: Why have you wrapped your f-string in another set of quotes? It should be just `values_list(f"Z{coid}",...)`.

Comment: That was it.  To understand the logic.  Why do the other fields require single quotes around the field name and the f"Z{}" doesn't?

Comment: They all require quotes. It doesn't matter if they're single or double.

Comment: When I try .values_list(f"Z{coid}", flat = True) I get  Cannot resolve keyword 'Z08732' into field. Choices are: blevel, coid, dlevel, facilitydimension, rlevel, slevel, user   It's pulling the correct value but doesn't go to the coid field.

Comment: I really don't understand what you are trying to do. `values_list` expects a list of fields. If Z+coid isn't the name of a field, why are you passing it into values_list?

Comment: coid is the name of the field, but the results I'm saving to the database if the selectedaccesslevel == 7 I want to put a Z in front of the value of coid.

Comment: Then have `datareducecode = OrgLevel.objects.filter(coid__exact = owner.coid.coid).values_list('coid', flat = True); datareducecode=[f'Z{value}' for value in datareducecode]`

Comment: that will work, thank you.

Comment: If you write the answer i'll mark your solution as correct.